# GeckoFX dynamic EventHandler

Tags: eventhandler, geckofx

Hay :)

I'm currently creating an application with GeckoFX60 and unfortunately I encountered a problem.
I am generating a new browser control for each tab.

```
Dim page As New TabPage("Tab" & TabControl_Main.TabPages.Count.ToString)
TabControl_Main.TabPages.Add(page)
Dim browser As New GeckoWebBrowser
page.Controls.Add(browser)
browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

Later I can use the individual browser controls tab based:

```
Dim browser As GeckoWebBrowser = TryCast(TabControl_Main.TabPages.Item(TabControl_Main.TabPages.Count - 1).Controls(0), GeckoWebBrowser)
browser.Navigate("bla.de")
```

But how can I now dynamically add and use the event handlers?

Or is there a simple variable that can be queried?
I just want to know if the Gecko is ready to load the page.

```
​GeckoWebBrowser.IsBusy
```

always gives me a fake one even though it's still in the shop.

mfg Fynn

Answer (score 0):

```
AddHandler browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf gfxCompleted



Private Sub gfxCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim selectedbrowser As GeckoWebBrowser = sender
        Form_Getty.ListBox_Main.Items.Add("Folgender Browser hat fertiggeladen: " & selectedbrowser.Name)
    End Sub
```

Got it